# Sqlite 3 special count

Tags: sqlite, count

I have this select:

```
SELECT itemID, item, collectionName, tagID, extra  FROM items INNER JOIN factors ON   items.itemID = factors.zotero_itemID WHERE collectionID = 3 AND (tagID = 11 OR tagID = 16) GROUP BY item
```

That gives me this result:

```
itemID  item    collectionName              tagID   extra
342     3       Políticas Públicas - Artigo 16      S
349     5       Políticas Públicas - Artigo 11      S
541     25      Políticas Públicas - Artigo 16      R
```

What can I do to count how many different flags are in extra field. Ex: S = 2 R=1
Important: I can have other values in extra field, like B, P (and other that I don't know, because is set by the user) and I need to count them when they occur.

The result can be like this:

```
extra    totals
S        2
R        1
```

But, it's very important that the Where clause be observed.

Is it possible to do?
Best regards

Comment: Show an example of the desired output.

Comment: Hi CL. I've edited the post to show an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youhuu! It's working now.

```
SELECT extra, count(extra) AS totals FROM 
(
SELECT extra FROM items INNER JOIN factors ON   items.itemID = factors.zotero_itemID     WHERE collectionID = 3 AND (tagID = 11 OR tagID = 16) GROUP BY item
) GROUP BY extra
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `group by` query:

```
select extra, count(*) as totals
from items 
group by extra;
```

Comment: OK but I need this Where and Group Clause "WHERE collectionID = 3 AND (tagID = 11 OR tagID = 16) GROUP BY item". The counting must respect this clause. Is it possible to do this? Maybe a nested query bu I don't know how to do ;)

Comment: @Britto Did you try just adding the WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes @CL. I've tried. It returns tree rows: extra/totals; S/2; S/1; R/1

Comment: I need something like: extra/totals; S/2; R/1 @CL. Otherwise the app wil sum the result and will produce S/3; R/1. Is there a way to execute a select count within the result of that other select?